# Expo - eas build android command throw Entity not authorized error

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I do not know why my bundling command:

```
eas build --platform android
```

keeps returning this error:

> CombinedError: [GraphQL] Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[bf4d40b0-5121-4c66-96ed-6be99586c703] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[2200e4b1-4483-428d-87f3-0643e995c424], action = READ,
> ruleIndex = -1)

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem. What happened was that I cloned a project from a friend who had tried to build, so the build command added his build config to the `app.json`

One of the values was the `projectId` at the bottom of the file.

It had an Entity not authorized because that `projectId` didn't belong to my Expo account.

To fix it, I just deleted the `extra` property in the `app.json` and built the project again. This time it would generate a `projectId` that belongs to my account.

Comment: deleting extra property in app.json and running eas build:configure again fixed the problem for me !

Answer (score 2):

As per this link, your projectId may be messed up.
https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1324

Make sure projectId is correct in app.json file

Answer (score 2):

1 ) Make sure if the projectId is the same between app.json and expo project in (https://expo.dev)

2 ) Make sure if you are logged in expo-cli with the right account:

- to know, use on terminal `$ npx expo whoami`
- to logout use `$ npx expo logout`
- to login use `$ npx expo login -u yourusername -p yourpassword`

3 ) Make sure the correct permissions are set in expo.dev platform

If the projectId in app.json is different of the Project ID in expo.dev platform, delete "extra.eas.projectId" from app.json, create a new project on expo.dev and follow the platform instructions to link your project.